# Code to make plt.plot go through the origin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, computer-science

I have a Pandas data frame called df with only 2 columns of numbers: x and y.
To make the line of best fit go through **the origin**, I have made this line of code:

```
x=df.iloc[1:28,0]
lst_sq_x=df.iloc[1:28,0].values.reshape(-1,1)
lst_sq_y=df.iloc[1:28,1] 

plt.plot(x, np.linalg.lstsq(lst_sq_x, lst_sq_y)[0][0])(x))
```

However, this line does not work (invalid syntax). Will you tell me what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: One thing that might help is to break your code into multiple steps for readability, e.g., `x=df.iloc[1:28,0]; lst_sq_x=df.iloc[1:28,0].values.reshape(-1,1); lst_sq_y=df.iloc[1:28,1]` etc as that will let you check each step individually and also make it much more clear

Comment: Worth noting as well, the [PEP 8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) recommend lines be no more than 79 characters

Comment: Thanks; I edited the way you said.

Comment: And did that clarify or resolve your error when you run the code?

Comment: Yes, it actually solved the issue. It was just a minor formatting error.